# Constraining coordination or bond lengths for certain atoms in VASP

Tags: vasp, molecular-dynamics, geometry

I have a structure composed of many MX4 tetrahedral units. When doing MD on this structure I find that just one M atom moves into a trigonal planar coordination (MX3). I was wondering how to set constraints such that the M atom is always bonded to 4 X atoms in a tetrahedral coordination environment.

I came across the [ICONST option](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/ICONST), but I'm not sure how to use it to implement the constraint for all the M atoms in my structure.

POSCAR:

```
Li6 P1 S5 Cl1
1.0
-4.929500 0.000000 -4.929500
4.929500 -4.929500 0.000000
-4.929500 -4.929500 0.000000
Li P S Cl
6 1 5 1
direct
0.370400 0.018000 0.018000 Li+
0.629600 0.611600 0.018000 Li+
0.964000 0.352400 0.018000 Li+
0.629600 0.611600 0.352400 Li+
0.036000 0.018000 0.611600 Li+
0.370400 0.018000 0.611600 Li+
1.000000 0.500000 0.500000 P5+
0.500000 0.250000 0.250000 S2-
0.761060 0.141590 0.619470 S2-
0.761060 0.619470 0.619470 S2-
0.238940 0.619470 0.619470 S2-
0.238940 0.619470 0.141590 S2-
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 Cl-
```

Comment: Would you like a purely VASP solution to this problem or does a solution implementing ASE work?  An example structure as an image (or even POSCAR) would be very helpful.  You can avoid the exact structure you are working on if you have some reason to.

Comment: Purely VASP solution would be ideal but I'm open to an ASE solution if that's the only or best way. I've included the POSCAR in my question that's similar to the structure I'm working on. They are PS4 tetrahedra. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you done a phonon mode analysis to see if this is a stable structure or if it is at a saddle point?  How you constrain your system might depend on what your goal of the MD simulation is.

Comment: I haven't done a phonon mode analysis but I know experimentally this structure is stable. It's been made in lab and the structure is resolved by single-crystal XRD. I know it should have only MX4 tetrahedra from the single-crystal structural refinement. I'm interested in studying the alkali ion mobility in the MD simulation

Comment: I will try to see if I can work out something reasonable in the next day or so.  I would suggest doing a phonon mode calculation (a reviewer might want to see it) as well as if this is single-crystal XRD have you considered it to be possibly only meta-stable?  Is your MD simulation at a higher temperature than it is stable?  Your level of theory may also not describe it well.  You could use a supercell and see if the site changes coordination in the supercell as well.  Not making this an answer because its somewhat side information.

Comment: Thanks that's useful information to consider! I'll try a phonon mode calculation. Will that basically tell me if the material is metastable or stable? So the MD simulation temp is not higher than it is stable. Experimentally I've confirmed the material is stable at these temperatures. As for level of theory - I'm using the typical functionals (GGA PBE) used for these sulfide based alkali ion conductors. I'll try a supercell as well and see if that changes things

Comment: DoubleKx, @TristanMaxson, I fear that the system will very soon complain that this conversation is going on too long in the question's comments, I suggest to carry on this very useful discussion in the [VASP room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109983/vasp). Tristan do you have an answer to DoubleKx's last comment?

Comment: @TristanMaxson any luck with figuring this out?

Comment: I never managed to figure this out sadly.  It was taking more time than I could afford to spend.  I am starting to believe the MD moves to the better state and maybe it should just be used as is.

Comment: @DoubleKx Any luck/update with this question?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP or anyone else would like to add an answer.